How can I limit maximum number of simultaneous open connections for group of postgres users
As an example, if I have 3 users in Postgres, lets call them user_a, user_b, user_c... How can I ensure that they cannot hold more than two open connections at the same time? I may also have a user called user_z, and I would be happy to have them hold over 100+ connections. So limiting the overall number of connections in the db is not an option.
I looked into connection limit inheritance for roles but I cannot seem to find a clear answer on if this is the right path to go down.

The best I can think of is an event trigger that triggers on login, checks the currently active sessions and throws a FATAL error if the quota is exceeded. That is not an elegant solution, but then the requirement is quite unusual.
